# Is it possible to declare a separate tablespace in interval partition?

Tags: oracle, indexing, partition, tablespace

I have a dedicated tablespace for data and a dedicated tablespace for index. I migrated a table to a interval partitioned table and rebuilt the indexes on a separate tablespace. Then new records entered the table, creating new interval partition.

My problem is that the partition and its index were both created on the data dedicated tablespace, instead of:

- the data on the data dedicated tablespace
- the index on the index dedicated tablespace

Is there a solution that does not require ongoing maintenance?

Answer (score 3):

You can change the default attributes for the index. New partitions will then use the partition you specify:

```
create tablespace table_data 
  datafile 'table_data.dbf' size 1M autoextend on;

create tablespace index_data 
  datafile 'index_data.dbf' size 1M autoextend on;

create table t (
  c1 int, c2 int
) partition by range ( c1 ) 
  interval ( 1 ) (
  partition p0 values less than ( 1 )
) tablespace table_data;

create index i on t ( c2 ) local;

insert into t values ( 1, 1 );
commit;

select partition_name, tablespace_name 
from   user_tab_partitions
where  table_name = 'T';

PARTITION_NAME   TABLESPACE_NAME   
P0               TABLE_DATA        
SYS_P622         TABLE_DATA     

select partition_name, tablespace_name  
from   user_ind_partitions
where  index_name = 'I';

PARTITION_NAME   TABLESPACE_NAME   
P0               TABLE_DATA        
SYS_P622         TABLE_DATA        

alter index i 
  modify default attributes tablespace index_data;

insert into t values ( 2, 2 );
commit;

select partition_name, tablespace_name 
from   user_tab_partitions
where  table_name = 'T';

PARTITION_NAME   TABLESPACE_NAME   
P0               TABLE_DATA        
SYS_P622         TABLE_DATA        
SYS_P623         TABLE_DATA     

select partition_name, tablespace_name  
from   user_ind_partitions
where  index_name = 'I';

PARTITION_NAME   TABLESPACE_NAME   
P0               TABLE_DATA        
SYS_P622         TABLE_DATA        
SYS_P623         INDEX_DATA
```